# After certbot nginx website isn’t working

Tags: python, nginx, flask, certbot

After [installing and running certbot successfully](https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/ubuntuxenial-nginx), my website shows me the following error message:

> This page isn’t working
> example.com redirected you too many times.
> Try clearing your cookies.
> ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

My `nginx` server configuration (`/etc/nginx/sites-available/myapp`) looks as follows:

```
server {

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    server_name www.example.com example.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    }

}

server {
    if ($host = www.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    server_name www.example.com example.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

The options of `/etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf` look as follows:

```
ssl_session_cache shared:le_nginx_SSL:1m;
ssl_session_timeout 1440m;

ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

ssl_ciphers "ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-$
```

If I run `curl -I http://example.com`, I get this:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)
Date: Mon, 10 Dec 2018 08:03:37 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 194
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://example.com/
```

If I run `curl -I https://example.com`, I get this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

But the browser still shows me `This page isn’t working`

Before this everything was working fine. Anybody has an idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Can you show the content of  `/etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf`?

Comment: @OrtomalaLokni I've updated the post

Comment: Do you have other files in `/etc/nginx/sites-available` ? If yes, can you include it in your question?

Comment: Okay, I've got some questions: 1, why does your port 80 bracket have 2 ifs if you are going to do the same in both of them, you could put a single location and do whatever. Does the application make any redirect? Try to go in  a web browser, and open the dev tools (F12)  and see what redirects are you getting through.

Comment: @OrtomalaLokni no other files

Comment: @flaixman my port 80 bracket have 2? what do you mean?

Comment: in the second server bracket, you have listen port 80, and www.example.com and example.com as servername (so only those will be listened there). Why differentiate between 2 (if $host= example.com) if then you will do the same (return 301 https://$host$request_uri;). Isn't simpler to do:

location / { return 301 https://$host$request_uri; } . Have you tried to use f12 in the browser and look at the "Network" tab? What is being redirected to where?

Comment: Cannot say much yet. My location block with simple forward looks like.
    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header client $http_client;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass_header client;
    }

Comment: @flaixman on port 80 it should `return 301 https://$host$request_uri` but on 443 it should return the localhost, which is flask running on gunicorn

Comment: Does your backend really awaits an HTTPS, not an HTTP connection over port 8000? Does in check or process an HTTP `Host` header somehow?

Comment: @IvanShatsky As you can see I am using nginx as a reverse proxy, so I have configured the certificate with nginx, and then nginx can "terminate" the encrypted connection, meaning that it will accept encrypted connections from the outside, but then use regular unencrypted connections to talk to your Flask backend.

Comment: So why do you use `proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:8000;`, not a `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;` in your config?

Comment: Yeah this is a typo. I tried to use https now and then and copy/pased it to stackoverflow, but it doesn work with http

Comment: Have you tried the developer tools in the browser so you can see what redirects are in the loop? Maybe your gunicorn application wants a secured connection, so you need to put the x-fowarded-proto to https while proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000; (because maybe it doesn't read the header correctly and it's constantly 301ing to https://example.com. You'll have the answer in the network tab of the developer tools of the browser (f12)

Comment: Can you run `curl -I https://www.example.com/` and post the output here?

Comment: @IvanShatsky I've updated my question

Comment: @flaixman the network tab shows me this: Request URL: https://example.com/
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 301 
Remote Address: [......]:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

Comment: Okay, so it looks like it doesn't read the Headers correctly. Can you include this header?:   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme; So the application can read the connection as secure (https). Let's see if it works like this, as it looks that the application is redirecting constantly to itself as https because it doesn't detect when the connection itself comes as https.